# How to decode an iOS assertion object?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, encryption, base64

I generate an assertion object using [DCAppAttestService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice) and send it to my Cloud Functions server - to verify that in app purchases come from legitimate instances of my app.

Here is my Swift code that, when an in-app purchase has been made:

1. Retrieves a one-time challenge (string) from my server
2. Using that string, along with client data, to generate a hash
3. Use that hash, and the device's `keyID`, to call [`generateAssertion()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573912-generateassertion)
4. Send a base64-encoded string of the assertion object and client data object

Swift:

```
func callSensitiveFunction(name: String, data: [String:String], completion: @escaping (HTTPSCallableResult?, Error?)->()){
    var functions = Functions.functions()
    var adjustedData: [String:String] = data
    guard let keyID = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "attestKeyID") else {
        print("no attest ID, return")
        return
    }
    let service = DCAppAttestService.shared
    // Retrieve the challenge string
    functions.httpsCallable("getChallengeString").call(data){ (result, error) in
        if let challengeString = result?.data as? String {
            // Retrieve the keyID (public key) which was saved at first launch
            guard let attestKeyID = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "attestKeyID") else { return print("No attestKeyID found") }
            // Add challenge string to request
            adjustedData["challenge"] = challengeString
            // Hash client data (which includes challenge string)
            guard let clientData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(adjustedData) else { return }
            let clientDataHash = Data(SHA256.hash(data: clientData))
            service.generateAssertion(attestKeyID, clientDataHash: clientDataHash) { assertion, err in
                guard error == nil else { return print("generateAssertion() error: \(error)") }
                let assertionString = assertion?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
                let clientDataString = clientData.base64EncodedString()
                adjustedData["assertionString"] = assertionString
                adjustedData["clientData"] = clientDataString
                functions.httpsCallable(name).call(adjustedData){ (result, error) in
                    completion(result, error)
                    print("function \(name) completed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I receive the `assertionString` in the backend (Node.js) - I'm not how how to decode it. Using this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/webauthnworks/webauthn-fido2-verifying-apple-anonymous-attestation-5eaff334c849) i've gotten this far:

```
const cbor = require("cbor");
const base64url = require('base64url');

let verifyAppleAnonymousAttestation = (assertionString) => {
    let assertionBuffer = base64url.toBuffer(assertionString);
    console.log(`assertionBuffer: ${assertionBuffer}`) // assertionBuffer: �isignatureXG0E!���56��r��@��@J�r+X������ڳ%� D��c! 
    let assertionStruct = cbor.decodeAllSync(assertionBuffer)[0];
    console.log(`assertionStruct[0]: ${assertionStruct[0]}`) // assertionStruct: [object Object]
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here to verify the assertion string. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server) *after* the `assertion` is decoded it looks like this:

```
{
  signature: <Buffer 30 45 02 20 ... >,
  authenticatorData: <Buffer 21 c9 9e 00 ... >
}
```

Any idea how I can extract all of the validating data from the `assertionString`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `service.generateKey` (you should NOT try to generate the `keyId` yourself without Apple) and `service.attestKey` on the device. This is how Apple designed the API and you can see this from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573911-attestkey?language=swift). You also should use your `Keychain` to store the `keyId` for future requests **only after** a successful chain of requests. Don't store invalid `keyId`s in the Keychain that you generated without the `DCAppAttestService` otherwise, you will not get stable behavior.

The general page for `DCAppAttestService` says you should certify the key after you generate it using it's opaque framework methods since it doesn't want to expose sensitive device information for security. You are fighting the framework. :-)

Follow the steps in the order provided [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice?language=swift).

> - Create a cryptographic key in the Secure Enclave by calling the generateKeyWithCompletionHandler: method.
> - Ask Apple to certify the key by calling the attestKey:clientDataHash:completionHandler: method.
> - Prepare an assertion of your app’s integrity to accompany any or all server requests using the
>   generateAssertion:clientDataHash:completionHandler: method.

Example code:

```
var keyId: String? // Make this a property on self.
var attestationObject: Data? // Make this a property on self.

// Catch the errors this throws out when you call it.
func callSensitiveFunction(name: String, data: [String:String], completion: @escaping (HTTPSCallableResult?, Error?)->()) throws {    
// Check if keyId exists in Keychain, if it doesn't start the request flow.
// Get clientData from first request (challenge) as you are.
let clientDataHash = Data(SHA256.hash(data: clientData))
let service = DCAppAttestService.shared
guard service.isSupported else { return } 
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
service.generateKey { keyId, error in
  // First check for errors in every step, obviously you can handle the errors differently (this is just a guide).
  guard !error else {
    group.leave()
    throw ValidationError(error.localizedDescription) // I assume we have defined a new enum Error type with associated values here. 
    return
  }
  self.keyId = keyId
  group.leave()
}
group.wait()
guard let keyId = self.keyId {
  throw ValidationError("Missing keyId")
  return
}
group.enter()
service.attestKey(keyId, clientDataHash: clientDataHash) { attestationObject, error in
  guard !error else {
    group.leave()
    throw ValidationError(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
  self.attestationObject = attestationObject
  group.leave()
}
// Now you need to send `attestationObject` to the server directly to validate server-side.
group.wait()
guard let attestationObject = self.attestationObject {
  throw ValidationError("Missing attestationObject")
  return
}
group.enter()
functions.httpsCallable(name).call(attestationObject) { (result, error) in
  guard !error else {
    group.leave()
    throw ValidationError(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
  group.leave()
}
// Now you only generate the assertion if the key was valid.
group.wait()
service.generateAssertion(keyId, clientDataHash: clientDataHash) { data, error in
  guard !error else {
    throw ValidationError(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
  // NOW store in the Keychain.
  completion(result, error)
  print("function \(name) completed")
}
}
```

I will limit my answer to iOS device code but the background and guidelines for verifying the key server-side can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server?language=swift).

I can also suggest using `DispatchGroup` instead of nested completion blocks - also make sure you call `callSensitiveFunction` on a background queue. You get the main reasons for your issue - the HTTPS request order needs to be precise, as well as using Apple's API guidelines. Otherwise, you will be inspecting the wrong object. :) I'm not sure if you want to throw errors, and I haven't tested this code (I don't have an API handy), but the rough idea is there.

Comment: Thanks. The `guard let keyID` in my code was generated using `service.generateKey()` on app launch. So I successfully send a valid assertion object (base64 encoded string) to my server. My issue is trying to validate the `assertion` on my Node.js server

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you call `service.attestKey` elsewhere in your code as well?

Comment: I do not. I choose to just verify every request (in-app purchase) on the server. I don't see the need to double-up.

Comment: I see. Well, I think that's the issue. Apple needs to certify that key internally on its own servers before `generateAssertion` - looks like you have the issue mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573911-attestkey?language=swift). `A compromised version of your app could falsify the verification result, thus circumventing App Attest.`

Comment: Thanks - I will make sure I verify the key with `attestKey()`. However, the main issue/complexity is still verifying the `assertion` on the server.

Comment: For verifying the payload, I think you should inspect the raw `attestationObject` sent as `Data` without decoding to a Base 64 string because it is not in that format. This seems to be what Apple is recommending. The `attestationObject` is in encoded CBOR format, to decode it and verify the payload you can try using [this library](https://github.com/arduino/cbor-js) or another similar library.

Comment: I am not sure whether the tutorial you are following is the route that Apple wants us to take because it uses a reverse-engineered unofficial Apple schema. Follow the steps in the documentation directly. If you can update the question with the official steps you took in JS code with the output, I can have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229595/discussion-between-pranav-kasetti-and-zorgan).

Comment: You should not store keyId in keychain, because keys in Enclave don't include in iCLoud backup. So you can have the following situation - keyId presents in keychain due to backup, but secret key absents in Enclave. 

Store keyId in some place that doesn't include in backup